# Pyspark standard scaler - excluding null values for mean calculation

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to use standardScaler for sparkML library for a dataframe with columns with null values. I would like to retain the null values, but when I use standard scaler with mean, the mean of the columns with null values also become null. Is there any way to make the standard scaler skip the null values for mean calculation ( like handleInvalid option in vector assembler) ?

Below is the code example

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
sqlContext = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').config("spark.submit.deployMode","client").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate() 

test_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2,None),(1,3,3),(1,4,8),(1,5,7),(1,6,8),
                                  (1,7,1),(1,8,6),(1,9,9),(1,10,3),(1,11,12)],schema=['col1','col2','col3'])
#%%

from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer,VectorIndexer,VectorAssembler,StandardScaler
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline,PipelineModel

assmbler  = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['col2','col3'],outputCol='col_vec',handleInvalid='keep')
sclr = StandardScaler(withMean=True,inputCol='col_vec',outputCol='col_scaled')
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[assmbler,sclr])
pipe_fit= pipeline.fit(test_df)
df_res = pipe_fit.transform(test_df)
```

After this if I try to get the mean values.

```
pipe_fit.stages[1].mean
Out[5]: DenseVector([6.5, nan])
```

As you can see the mean of the second column is nan. Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [fit method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fe412b666a2d37ef34202eb9cf47aa469c336798/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/StandardScaler.scala#L107) of Spark's StandardScaler uses `Summarizer.metrics("mean", "std")` to calculate  the mean of a column:

```scala
val Row(mean: Vector, std: Vector) = dataset
  .select(Summarizer.metrics("mean", "std").summary(col($(inputCol))).as("summary"))
  .select("summary.mean", "summary.std")
  .first()
```

The [Summarizer class](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fe412b666a2d37ef34202eb9cf47aa469c336798/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/stat/Summarizer.scala#L83) itself has no option to ignore `null` or `NaN`/`None` values, so there is no built-in solution for the problem.

### There are several options to handle the issue:

#### Filter out the the None values before fitting the pipeline

```python
test_df = test_df.filter("not col2 is null and not col3 is null")
```

#### Replace missing values with a constant value

```python
test_df = test_df.fillna(0) #or any other value that is appropriate for the task
```

#### Using an Imputer

Add an [Imputer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.Imputer.html) to the pipeline to replace missing values with either the mean, the median or the most frequent value of the feature:

```python
from pyspark.ml.feature import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(inputCols=['col2', 'col3'], outputCols=['col2i', 'col3i'])
assmbler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['col2i','col3i'],outputCol='col_vec',handleInvalid='keep')
sclr = StandardScaler(withMean=True,inputCol='col_vec',outputCol='col_scaled')
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[imputer,assmbler,sclr])
pipe_fit= pipeline.fit(test_df)
df_res = pipe_fit.transform(test_df)
```

`pipe_fit.stages[2].mean` now returns

```
DenseVector([6.5, 6.3])
```

as the missing value in `col3` has been replaced with the mean value of this column.

With the [strategy parameter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.Imputer.html#pyspark.ml.feature.Imputer.strategy) either the median or the most common value can be used instead of the mean, but using the mean is the default value.

#### Scale the required columns without a StandardScaler

Using the standard Spark SQL functions [mean](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#mean) and [stddev](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#stddev) it is possible to implement a similar logic like the StandardScaler. Both SQL functions handle `None` values nicely.

```python
cols = ['col2', 'col3'] # the columns that should be scaled
mean_and_std_cols=[c for col in cols for c in 
    (F.mean(col).alias(f"{col}_mean"),F.stddev(col).alias(f"{col}_std"))]
mean_and_std = test_df.select(mean_and_std_cols).first()
scaled_cols=[((F.col(col) - mean_and_std[f"{col}_mean"])
    /mean_and_std[f"{col}_std"]).alias(f"{col}_s") for col in cols]
test_df = test_df.select(test_df.columns + scaled_cols)
```

This logic adds the two columns `col2_s` and `col3_s` to the dataframe that contain the scaled values. `mean_and_std` contains the actual values for mean and std:

```
Row(col2_mean=6.5, col2_std=3.0276503540974917, col3_mean=6.333333333333333, col3_std=3.4641016151377544)
```

The newly created columns `col2_s` and `col3_s` can now be used as input columns for the VectorAssembler:

```python
assmbler  = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['col2_s','col3_s'],outputCol='col_vec',handleInvalid='keep')
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[assmbler])
pipe_fit= ...
```

This option might be a bit slower on large datasets than the original scaler as the values for mean and std are not approximated but calculated exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. For my use, it is important that the null columns remain undisturbed. There are some custom logics on the transformed columns based on where the null occurs. Filling with a substitute value and then reverting back to original null value after pre processing would be a over kill too. Any other better method to do this?

Comment: @Raghu I have added another option where the values are scaled explicitly with some lines of code

Comment: thanks! The problem in this approach is that when infering using the pipeline model, the mean and std is not stored anywhere. If I had used standard scaler on pipeline , then I can use the training data distribution to transform the inference data with no explicit memory needed.

Comment: This is very valid point. The problem is as soon as a `None` value is placed into a Vector, it is converted to `NaN` (you can try `a=np.array([1.0, None, 2.0])` 
`Vectors.dense(a)`). This `NaN` value corrupts then the calculation of mean and std. The only way I see at the moment is to save the value of `mean_and_std` and then apply the same logic on the inference data again.

Comment: Guess then the only option is a new feature request ..

Comment: Thanks a lot for the efforts. I see this as the best suited answer for now

Comment: I thought scaler's automatically ignore np.nan value when getting fit, no? I am using min-max scaler and cannot find any mention in the docs.